# Pipeline keeps giving Error: spawn ps ENOENT

Tags: node.js, cypress, gitlab-ci

I'm new to git CI and I'm trying to create a pipeline for a school project. I need to run some tests with Cypress through the CI but I get an `Error: spawn ps ENOENT`.

The CI job:

```
cypress-test-job:
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd frontend-webpack/
    - echo "Testing frontend with Cypress"
    - npm ci
    - npm run test
    - echo "Testing complete"
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "seminar-week5-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx webpack-cli",
    "build:dev": "npx webpack-cli --mode=development",
    "start": "npx webpack serve",
    "watch": "npx webpack serve",
    "lint": "npx eslint src/**.js src/js/**.js",
    "cy:test": "npx cypress run",
    "test:headless": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/integration/ToDo_tests.js",
    "test": "start-server-and-test start http-get://localhost:8080 cy:test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "sass": "^1.49.11",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "cypress": "^9.5.3",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

The failed output of the pipeline:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.9.0~beta.68.g1283960c (1283960c)
  on green-4.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default ntHFEtyX
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor
00:41
Using Docker executor with image cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97 ...
Pulling docker image cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97 ...
Using docker image sha256:beaac0b58885bf17f2b91ce142daaed6658aaee184bff7c8f114e2210db567cc for cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97 with digest cypress/browsers@sha256:e55e133a7b66e1e0fd13b8e7db1f545771ed3a98f76fc662fce268d02ab0aff9 ...
Preparing environment
00:02
Running on runner-nthfetyx-project-34382765-concurrent-0 via runner-nthfetyx-shared-1649414442-4ad4be93...
Getting source from Git repository
00:12
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/saxion.nl/hbo-ict/development-tools/web/38/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out 8c002ea2 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
02:45
Using docker image sha256:beaac0b58885bf17f2b91ce142daaed6658aaee184bff7c8f114e2210db567cc for cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97 with digest cypress/browsers@sha256:e55e133a7b66e1e0fd13b8e7db1f545771ed3a98f76fc662fce268d02ab0aff9 ...
$ cd frontend-webpack/
$ echo "Testing frontend with Cypress"
Testing frontend with Cypress
$ npm ci
added 624 packages, and audited 625 packages in 55s
78 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
found 0 vulnerabilities
$ npm run test
> seminar-week5-client@1.0.0 test
> start-server-and-test start http-get://localhost:8080 cy:test
1: starting server using command "npm run start"
and when url "[ 'http-get://localhost:8080' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200
running tests using command "npm run cy:test"
> seminar-week5-client@1.0.0 start
> npx webpack serve
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/builds/saxion.nl/hbo-ict/development-tools/web/38/frontend-webpack/src' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /builds/saxion.nl/hbo-ict/development-tools/web/38/frontend-webpack/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
<i> [webpack-dev-middleware] wait until bundle finished: /
asset app.bundle.js 2.19 MiB [emitted] [minimized] [big] (name: main) 1 related asset
asset a5441281b140aaf5cb21.png 80.6 KiB [emitted] [immutable] [from: src/images/delete.png] (auxiliary name: main)
asset index.html 419 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 27.5 KiB 13 modules
orphan modules 19.9 KiB [orphan] 9 modules
javascript modules 987 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 980 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.75 KiB 6 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 56.8 KiB 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 4.4 KiB 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 115 KiB 4 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 3.52 KiB 3 modules
    + 4 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 6.81 KiB
    ./src/app.js + 1 modules 2.64 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./src/styles/appStyle.scss 2.41 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/appStyle.scss 1.76 KiB [built] [code generated]
./src/images/delete.png 42 bytes (javascript) 80.6 KiB (asset) [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.72.0 compiled successfully in 19130 ms
> seminar-week5-client@1.0.0 cy:test
> npx cypress run
[STARTED] Task without title.
[SUCCESS] Task without title.
[310:0408/104418.838935:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Address does not contain a colon
[310:0408/104418.839032:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Address does not contain a colon
[310:0408/104418.846171:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
[475:0408/104418.911107:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is 
tput: unknown terminal "xterm   npm_config_loglevel warn   npm_config_unsafe_perm true"
====================================================================================================
  (Run Starting)
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Cypress:        9.5.3                                                                          │
  │ Browser:        Electron 94 (headless)                                                         │
  │ Node Version:   v16.14.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)                                                 │
  │ Specs:          1 found (ToDo_tests.js)                                                        │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                                                                    
  Running:  ToDo_tests.js                                                                   (1 of 1)
[310:0408/104421.132271:ERROR:bus.cc(392)] Failed to connect to the bus: Address does not contain a colon
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
  My ToDo list
    ✓ can add new todo items (10167ms)
    ✓ can remove todo items (7887ms)
    ✓ Try adding duplicate item (3738ms)
    ✓ Delete the rest (2554ms)
  4 passing (25s)
  (Results)
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ Tests:        4                                                                                │
  │ Passing:      4                                                                                │
  │ Failing:      0                                                                                │
  │ Pending:      0                                                                                │
  │ Skipped:      0                                                                                │
  │ Screenshots:  0                                                                                │
  │ Video:        true                                                                             │
  │ Duration:     24 seconds                                                                       │
  │ Spec Ran:     ToDo_tests.js                                                                    │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
  (Video)
  -  Started processing:  Compressing to 32 CRF                                                     
    Compression progress:  68%
  -  Finished processing: /builds/saxion.nl/hbo-ict/development-tools/web/38/frontend   (20 seconds)
                          -webpack/cypress/videos/ToDo_tests.js.mp4                                 
    Compression progress:  100%
tput: unknown terminal "xterm   npm_config_loglevel warn   npm_config_unsafe_perm true"
====================================================================================================
  (Run Finished)
       Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ ✔  ToDo_tests.js                            00:24        4        4        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    ✔  All specs passed!                        00:24        4        4        -        -        -  
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn ps ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn ps',
  path: 'ps',
  spawnargs: [ '-A', '-o', 'ppid,pid,stat,comm' ]
}
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
Uploading artifacts...
frontend-webpack/cypress/videos/*.mp4: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=2310380359 responseStatus=201 Created token=gaMq6mXk
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: This probably means the `ps` command is not available in the `cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97` image. Probably simmilar to this https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test/issues/132#issuecomment-448581335

Comment: @Molda is right, try using „sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install procps“ in your pipeline to install what is missing as also suggested in the github issue.

Comment: Why `cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim` does not contain `ps` command out of the box ? Maybe this error comes from an unexpected use of something within Cypress, any clue ?

Comment: `-slim` images are meant to be smaller, so maybe they trim the `procps` package.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was mentioned [here](https://github.com/bahmutov/start-server-and-test/issues/132):

> I had the same problem in a different project. The reason is that alpine **doesn't have the 'ps' command** installed by default.
>
> I fixed it by installing it in my container:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install procps
```

That indeed solved it for me as well.

Comment: It also solved a hot reloading issue that I had with node:21-bullseye-slim image for a node/nestjs application.
Thanks!